# How can I share a pptp vpn with lan?

Tags: 14.04, vpn, sharing

I need to share a PPTP VPN connection with a LAN connected to my PC ( UBUNTU 14.04 ).
In windows there was a part named change adapter settings which I could share my VPN connection to a specific connection on the PC.
Now I need to do it using my ubuntu.
What shall I do?